# Why is previous-line skipping lines?

Tags: motion

When I use the up arrow or C-p to invoke `previous-line`, some lines - even ones with content - are skipped (seemingly at random, though I am sure it is not). For example, this is the sequence of events when I press C-p (or up arrow) 6 times consecutively, with the cursor beginning in column 1 of the bottom line:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Step 3:

[image]

Step 4:

[image]

Step 5:

[image]

Step 6:

[image]

As you can see, in step 4 and step 6, lines are being skipped. I thought it might have something to do with `line-move-visual` (which I have set to `t`), but changing it to `nil` doesn't affect this behavior. Also, the behaviour is not specific to any mode, it seems to have something to do with how text is spaced in the buffer. Also, this doesn't happen with `next-line` (C-n/down arrow). Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: A wild guess: Are you using emacs 24.3? That bug was fixed 24.4 onwards. https://github.com/alpaker/Fill-Column-Indicator/issues/31#issuecomment-16618823

Comment: Otherwise, try to repro it starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). If it reproduces, and the cited bug is apparently not the cause, then report it: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If you cannot repro it without your init file, recursively bisect that file until you locate the code that causes the problem.

Comment: @kaushalmodi , that did the trick. I had to compile emacs 24.4 from source, but that was a fun new experience, and it solved the problem!

Comment: @elethan Great! But then why not build an even later stable version: 24.5?

Comment: ...Didn't think about that...The tutorial I was going off of was for 24.4, so I just went with that without checking what the latest stable version was. I am working on getting 24.5 right now. Is there an easy way to completely get rid of the previous version? It seems like just removing the directory and everything in it still left a lot of stuff lying around...

Comment: @elethan I install emacs in version specific folders.. something like `./configure --prefix=~/some_dir/emacs/version`. I don't know if `make uninstall` would work but give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kaushalmodi guessed, I was seeing the effects of a bug in my version of Emacs, and solved the problem by compiling the latest stable version of Emacs from source (since I couldn't find anything later than 24.3 to install with apt). This was easier than I thought it would be, and I did so following the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437255/how-to-install-emacs-24-4-on-ubuntu) (I just replaced the 24.4 with 24.5 to get the current stable release, again per @kaushalmodi's suggestion).